# pinv return svd failed when use mex + armadillo in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, mex, armadillo

Even the pseudo inverse matrix calculation not necessarily needs a invertible matrix, I'm using a non-singular matrix to test. When I use just armadillo, the answer is returned without errors. I'm using the next code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    mat A,B;
    A << 1 << 2 << endr << 3 << 4 << endr;
    A.print("A:");
    B = pinv(A);
    B.print("B:");

    return 0;
}
```

This code was adapted to mex (thanks @claes-rolen for this):

```
#include "armaMex.hpp"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
     int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) 
{   
    mat A =  conv_to<mat>::from(armaGetPr(prhs[0],true));
    plhs[0] = armaCreateMxMatrix(A.n_rows,A.n_cols, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    armaSetPr(plhs[0],conv_to<mat>::from(pinv(A))); 
}
```

But when tested with the previous matrix, it returns svd-failed. Someone can help why this happen, even with a matrix non-singular. The above code works when I change pinv() for inv(), but for my application I need it work with pinv().

Comment: Tried your code both `inv()` and `pinv()` and it worked fine. I use Armadillo 6.7, Visual Studio 2015 and Matlab 2016a on Windows10.

Comment: @ClaesRolen I'm using Ubuntu 16 here. I found a similar question on  matlab's forum and I can now run the code without problems. It was just set some system variables before running matlab. One more time, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

To use pinv() on matlab without errors, follow the next steps:

In command line, set the next variables:

```
export BLAS_VERSION="/usr/lib/libblas.so"
export LAPACK_VERSION="/usr/lib/liblapack.so"
```

Execute matlab and compile mex code:

```
mex prog.cpp -larmadillo -llapack -lblas
```

This works on Ubuntu 16.